# CS50 Resize Less: strange bmp output

Tags: c, image-resizing, cs50

I've been through the logic dozens times and it seems correct, I have no idea why the output is the way it is... Could someone help to explain why this logic output is wrong?

I cannot do debugging since I don't know how to check the content of `RGBTRIPLE* out_row`. I can't printf it with %i, %s, %c, %d... I'm really clueless...
Thank you so much in advance...

**input**
[image: input]

**output with scale factor 4**
[image: output with scale factor 4]

**smiley input**
[image: smiley input]

**smiley output with scale factor 1**
[image: smiley output with scale factor 1]

This is the code below, I've compared the output of `BITMAPFILEHEADER` and `BITMAPINFOHEADER` to the sample and they seems to be correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // get n factor
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (n > (pow(2,23)) - 1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: n is too big\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n infile outfile\n");
        return 5;
    }
    else if (n <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: n is too small\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n infile outfile\n");
        return 6;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }
    printf("biSizeImage: %i, bfSize: %i\n", bi.biSizeImage, bf.bfSize);
    printf("inputheight:%i\n", bi.biHeight);

    // save input data to variable
    int in_width = bi.biWidth;
    int in_height = bi.biHeight;
    printf("temp inheight:%i\n", in_height);
    int in_padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // update outfile's HEADER
    bi.biWidth *= n;
    bi.biHeight *= n;
    int out_padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    bi.biSizeImage = ((sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bi.biWidth) + out_padding) * abs(bi.biHeight);
    bf.bfSize = bi.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    printf("new_biSizeImage: %i, new_bfSize: %i\n", bi.biSizeImage, bf.bfSize);

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // allocate memory to store output row
    RGBTRIPLE* out_row = malloc(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));

    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(in_height); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // initialize counter to write out_row
        int counter = 0;

        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < in_width; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write the triple to out_row times n factor
            for (int o = 0; o < n ; o++)
            {
                out_row[counter] = triple;
                counter++;
            }

            // skip over padding, if any
            fseek(inptr, in_padding, SEEK_CUR);

            // write the out_row result and repeat vertically
            for (int m = 0; m < n; m++)
            {
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(out_row, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), bi.biWidth, outptr);

                // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
                for (int k = 0; k < out_padding; k++)
                {
                    fputc(0x00, outptr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // release malloc
    free(out_row);

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What OS are you running on?  You're opening all your files in *text* mode:  `FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");` should be `FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "rb");` to ensure binary mode.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it was not the issue, in cs50, we only copy that part from a program that copy a file from a bitmap, I've checked it and they works fine. The output starts to get funny only when I try to code the resizing logic :)

Comment: Tip: Consider `fread(&bf, sizeof bf, 1, inptr);` instead `fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);`.  Less likely to code wrong, it is shorter, easier to review and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I've never taken CS50, but as far as debugging goes try using a debugger like gdb. Although you might not know the type for printf, I am confident you can print it out using gdb's print statement. If it is an RGB value, I am guessing its a tuple with (R, G, B). Seeing that its an RGBTRIPLE *, it might be a pointer to a tuple. Hope that was helpful. Here is a link to a gdb guide. https://beej.us/guide/bggdb/

Comment: Thank you for your kind info, I shall read the documentation later on :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, I've found the bug... I just realize, this is a very dumb question. It's just a matter of a wrong bracket within the for loop. Specifically, the part of  `// iterate over pixels in scanline` missing an `}`.

This is the first time I'm using stack overflow so I'm not sure if I need to answer this or delete this question.